# How to transform labels text into numerical values in R language

Tags: r, svm

When I tune `SVM` with `R` language, there is a mistake that the function need a numerical value so that it can do regression. I want to know, how could transform labels text into numerical values or another way to tune `SVM`. `V2` is the name of label column, containing label text.

**My Code:**

```
dataset <- read.csv('wdbc.csv',head = FALSE)
index <- 1:nrow(dataset)

testindex <- sample(index, trunc(length(index)*30/100))

testset <- dataset[testindex,]

trainset <- dataset[-testindex,]


#Assigment : find the optimal SVM for calssification (try linear, radial and tunning)
#start code
#Prepare the traindata
Nonum_train_data <- subset(trainset, select=-V1)
x_train <- subset(Nonum_train_data, select=-V2)
y_train <- subset(Nonum_train_data, select=V2)

#prepare testdata
Nonum_test_data <- subset(testset, select=-V1)
x_test <- subset(Nonum_test_data, select=-V2)

svm_tune <- tune(svm, train.x=x_train, train.y=y_train, 
             kernel="radial", ranges=list(cost=10^(-1:2), gamma=c(.5,1,2)))

print(svm_tune)
```

Comment: Can you show the head of your data?

Comment: Maybe `as.numeric(as.factor(<labels text>))`?

Comment: Thanks. I found that  `unlist()` can do this